# Openssl s_client: extract last certificate

Tags: openssl, sed

I can ouput all the certification chain from a remote website by using the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.fr:443 -servername www.google.fr -showcerts 2>/dev/null | sed --quiet '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
```

But now i would like to be able to extract only the last certificate in the chain, is there a simple way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple oneliner:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.fr:443 -servername www.google.fr -showcerts 2>/dev/null | sed --quiet '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | csplit --prefix=outfile - "/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/+1" "{*}" --elide-empty-files --quiet
```

It's working on my CentOS, it's make three files `outfile00`, `outfile01` and `outfile02`. So you could take certificate that you want from file.

Comment: don't work on my ubuntu, and i would like to ouput to stdout because after i want to do a hash with `openssl dgst -sha256`

Comment: you should get the certificate hash from ``openssl x509 -in my.crt -text -noout`` and that's the real cryptographic hash not a hash over the base64 representation of the certificate.